# What do '4eCe' and '2eCe' mean in Lalo's Symphonie Espagnole?

Tags: violin, articulation

May I know what does **'4eCe'** & **'2eCe'** mean in this context?

**I got this sheet music from imslp*.
[image: Extract of the piece]

Comment: Please be more specific about where this image comes from. I've made a guess in my answer, but there are many options to search through on IMSLP, and the more specific you are, the easier it is to get quick and accurate answers.

Comment: sure, maybe I can put the link down here, but I'll have to check if there's any info about the publisher

Comment: @Vehrnesto - It's from IMSLP. That website *will* have information about the publisher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're abbreviations for the French "quatrième corde", meaning "fourth string", and "deuxième corde", meaning "second string".

It appears that the posted excerpt comes from the solo violin part, first movement, to the French piano/violin edition. In that edition, see, for example, measure 13:

[image: Lalo "Symphonie Espagnole", violin, m. 13]

Comment: (And, to clarify further, the "fourth string" is G and "second string" is A, meaning that the snippet in the answer above is in sixth position. The dashed lines after the indication mean you continue on G string; the 2e Corde indication allows you onto A string, at first in first position, then into 3rd. This would have been the obvious interpretation even without the marking, but the 2e Corde in the second line is needed to tell the difference between the "3" finger indicating 1st position on E or 5th on A.